# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer as numpy randon.randn python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In this code

```
N = 4
M = 30

# Generar datos a partir de 3 clusters diferentes:

X1 = 10 + 2*np.random.randn(M/3,N)
X2 = -10 + 5*np.random.randn(M/3,N) 
X3 = 1*np.random.randn(M/3,N)
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/tema3/3.18_MDS.py", line 16, in <module>
    X1 = 10 + 2*int(np.random.randn(M/3,N)) # cluster 1 (dispersion media)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1420, in mtrand.RandomState.randn
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1550, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 167, in mtrand.cont0_array
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I'm not sure about the problem because I think I'm not pasing any float to randn.

Comment: python3 i presume? try looking at the output of `print(M/3)`

Comment: yes  it is python3

Comment: integer division in python 3 returns a float. If you want to truncate (as python2 did) you need to use `//`. Try replacing `M/3` with `M//3` everywhere.

Comment: Even though this is a dupe, and OP *should* have tried debugging the program with a few print statements, I think the downvotes here are a little harsh. The change in behavior of the `/` operator is not obvious.

Comment: @pault It's not the change in behavior of `/` that's the problem, it's numpy not accepting `30/3 = 10.0` as an integer (even though it is an integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3 integer division with `/` returns a float. You need to use `//` to get an integer (rounded down).

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>

>>> type(1/1)
<class 'float'>

>>> type(1//1)
<class 'int'>

>>> 1/2
0.5

>>> 1//2
0
```